# Add more question with multiple options JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to add multiple questions with multiple options, some question have 2 options some have 3 and so on. Please guide me what exactly I am doing wrong. Add more is working fine with for outer box but inner box having issues. Please check and help me thanks

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Add more</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .border {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 2rem;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }

        .border.inner {
            border-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="action.php" method="post">
            <div class="long_box">
                <div class="border">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label>Question</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="question[]"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="border inner">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="long_box_inner">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label>Question Option</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="option[]"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <br>
                                <input type="submit" class="long_add_more_inner btn btn-success" name="Submit" value="Add More Inner">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="long_add_more btn btn-success" name="Submit" value="Add more">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Add More Box
            var long_max_fields = 10000;
            var long_wrapper = $(".long_box");
            var long_add_button = $(".long_add_more");

            var lng = 1;
            var lng_counter = 0;

            $(document).on('click', ".long_add_more", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (lng < long_max_fields) {
                    lng++;
                    lng_counter++;
                    htmloutputlng = "";

                    htmloutputlng += `
<div class="long_ajax_box">

<div class="border">                      

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Question</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="question[]"></textarea>
</div>                         

</div> 

<div class="border inner">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Question Option</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="option[]"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<br>
<input type="submit" class="long_add_more_inner btn btn-success" name="Submit" value="Add More Inner">
</div>

</div>

</div> 

<input type="submit" class="long_remove_button btn btn-danger" value="Remove">

</div>

</div>
`;

                    $(long_wrapper).append(htmloutputlng);

                }

            });

            $(long_wrapper).on("click", ".long_remove_button", function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                $(this).closest('div.long_ajax_box').remove();
                lng--;

            });

            // Add More Box Inner
            var long_inner_max_fields = 10;
            var long_inner_wrapper = $(".long_box_inner");
            var long_inner_add_button = $(".long_add_more_inner");

            var lng_inner = 1;
            var lng_inner_counter = 0;

            $(document).on('click', ".long_add_more_inner", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (lng_inner < long_inner_max_fields) {
                    lng_inner++;
                    lng_inner_counter++;
                    htmloutputlng_inner = "";

                    htmloutputlng_inner += `

<div class="long_box_inner_ajax">

<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Question Option</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="option[]"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12"><br>
<input type="submit" class="long_inner_remove_button btn btn-danger" value="Remove">
</div>

</div>

`;

                    $(long_inner_wrapper).append(htmloutputlng_inner);

                }

            });

            $(long_inner_wrapper).on("click", ".long_inner_remove_button", function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                $(this).closest('div.long_box_inner_ajax').remove();
                lng_inner--;

            });

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please format your unreadable code https://htmlformatter.com/

Comment: You can consider using array to store the fields

Comment: if you see my code i am already using array but my concern is html flow with jquery. if you run my code and test you will get my point. Thanks

Comment: I do not see any array in the file. You are setting the `name` attribute of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your

```js
$(long_inner_wrapper).append(htmloutputlng_inner);
```

to

```js
$(this).parent().siblings(long_inner_wrapper).append(htmloutputlng_inner);
```

The inner option is always adding to the first `.long_inner_wrapper` class match element. You have to make it dynamic and always add to the closest `.long_inner_wrapper` instead.

Also , you need to change your

```
$(long_inner_wrapper).on("click", ".long_inner_remove_button", function(e) {
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", ".long_inner_remove_button", function(e) {
```

Otherwise , your inner remove button will not work.

### Bonus:

I've formatted your code to make it look nicer.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Add more</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <style>
      .border {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 2rem;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top: 1rem;
      }

      .border.inner {
        border-color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form action="action.php" method="post">
        <div class="long_box">
          <div class="border">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Question</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="question[]"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="border inner">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="long_box_inner">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Question Option</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="option[]"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <br />
                  <input
                    type="submit"
                    class="long_add_more_inner btn btn-success"
                    name="Submit"
                    value="Add More Inner"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          type="submit"
          class="long_add_more btn btn-success"
          name="Submit"
          value="Add more"
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-success"
          name="Submit"
          value="Submit"
        />
      </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Add More Box
        var long_max_fields = 10000;
        var long_wrapper = $(".long_box");
        var long_add_button = $(".long_add_more");

        var lng = 1;
        var lng_counter = 0;

        $(document).on("click", ".long_add_more", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (lng < long_max_fields) {
            lng++;
            lng_counter++;
            htmloutputlng = "";

            htmloutputlng += `
            <div class="long_ajax_box">
                <div class="border">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label>Question</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="question[]"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="border inner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="long_box_inner">
                        <label>Question Option</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="option[]"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <br />
                        <input
                            type="submit"
                            class="long_add_more_inner btn btn-success"
                            name="Submit"
                            value="Add More Inner"
                        />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        type="submit"
                        class="long_remove_button btn btn-danger"
                        value="Remove"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
            $(long_wrapper).append(htmloutputlng);
          }
        });
        $(long_wrapper).on("click", ".long_remove_button", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).closest("div.long_ajax_box").remove();
          lng--;
        });

        // Add More Box Inner
        var long_inner_max_fields = 10;
        var long_inner_wrapper = $(".long_box_inner");
        var long_inner_add_button = $(".long_add_more_inner");

        var lng_inner = 1;
        var lng_inner_counter = 0;

        $(document).on("click", ".long_add_more_inner", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (lng_inner < long_inner_max_fields) {
            lng_inner++;
            lng_inner_counter++;
            htmloutputlng_inner = "";
            htmloutputlng_inner += `
            <div class="long_box_inner_ajax">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Question Option</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="option[]"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="submit"
                        class="long_inner_remove_button btn btn-danger"
                        value="Remove"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
            $(this).parent().siblings(long_inner_wrapper).append(htmloutputlng_inner);
          }
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".long_inner_remove_button", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).closest("div.long_box_inner_ajax").remove();
          lng_inner--;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```